# Wit.ai intent issues

Tags: nlp, bots, training-data, wit.ai

I am having real difficulty in understanding the intent part in Wit.ai. When I go to the understanding tab inside an app it shows me intent as a user defined entity.

Do we need to create intents as a user entity or do we need to create intents as a separate in-build entity. Just today when I was going through their HTTP API they first took me to the docs of version [20141022](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20141022)
 and then to the version [20160526](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526) in a matter of 15 minutes (meaning they are not stable with http api versions?). In the older version I see that for posting intent there is a separate API which is deprecated in the latter (newer version).

Also I went through some of the apps from the explore section and in each one of them I could see that intent is a different property altogether.

How should I treat the intent?

Considering the newer versions of the API if I take intent as a User defined entity and then add another entity with the search strategy trait. Wit.ai internally removes my expression for the other entity. I also need some help in understanding how this flow is working?

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of Wit.ai, `intent` is not a special, built-in entity anymore. It's just a user-defined entity that's created for you when you create an app. The search strategy is normally `trait`.

If you add another entity with `trait`, it will be completely orthogonal to `intent`. What do you mean by "Wit.ai internally removes my expression"?

Don't hesitate to explain what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have some data with me, I added it using Wit.ai http apis. I added 3 entities intent (trait), type_of_process (trait), sub_process (keywords). I added first the expressions and values for entity type_of_process and in the interface I can see all of my expressions. Then I add the values and expressions for entity "intent", I get all the values and expressions of entity intent but are left with only two expressions for type_of_process... I need to understand how is this happening.

Comment: @ArpitGoyal can you please email your app URL (wit.ai/...) to contact at wit.ai? I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I am researching wit.ai, though have a different need for my project: upscale voice-control home automation, that needs to stay local and work regardless of the Internet/Cloud outages. I am definitely in need of your expertise. Could you contact me on LinkedIn (I have a rather unique name) or at alex@px100systems.com, since SO doesn't allow personal communication. I'm an engineer (technical co-founder), not recruiter.